# MySQL - Improving Related Results (Getting terrible results)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, search

I want to improve my related results query for my video site. I consider 3 elements on my query; Title, description and tags.

I get really weird and non-related results on my videos. On the other hand, when I get correct results on some of the video series, order is completely wrong.

**Example for wrong result**

```
Video : sometext funny video
Expected : sometext2 funny video, sometext3 funny video, sometext funny 
sometext video. (AVAILABLE ON SYSTEM & DB)
Result : some-non-related-text1, some-non-related-text2 .. after 8-9 result 
sometext2 funny video... etc
```

**Example for correct result but false order;**

```
X Movie Ep 1
X Movie Ep 15
X Movie Ep 2
X Movie Ep 33
X Movie Ep 46
X Movie Ep 5
```

How I obtain `$key` value;

```
$pieces = array_filter(explode(" ", str_replace(array('(',')') , '', $video->title)));
$pieces2 = array_filter(explode(",", str_replace(array('(',')') , '', $video->tags)));
$pieces = array_merge($pieces, $pieces2);
$par = array();
$par[] = str_replace(array('(',')') , '', $video->title);
foreach($pieces as $p){
    if (strlen($p) > 2) {
        if (strlen($p) < 4)     {
            $par[] = $p . '*';
            }else{
            $par[] = $p;
            }
        }
    }
$key = toDb(implode(",", $par));
```

My query;

```
SELECT
   ". $ options.",
   ".DB_PREFIX."users.name,
   MATCH (title, description, tags) AGAINST ('".$key."' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS relevance,
   MATCH (title) AGAINST ('".$key."' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS title_relevance 
FROM
   ".DB_PREFIX."videos 
   LEFT JOIN
      ".DB_PREFIX."users 
      ON ".DB_PREFIX."videos.user_id = ".DB_PREFIX."users.id 
WHERE
   MATCH (title, description, tags) AGAINST('".$key."' IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
   AND ".DB_PREFIX."videos.pub > 0 
ORDER by
   title_relevance DESC,
   relevance DESC limit 1,
   ".get_option('related-nr', 12)."
```

What can I do to achieve better related results? Should I create a set of common words and exclude them ?

Comment: Your query is a bit weird. However, your `toDb` function is unknown to me. Anyway, it looks like you're comma-concatenating your search terms, however match in boolean mode doesn't need those (take a peek at the manual). since we don't actually know your database instance, you might want to put up an sqlfiddle with the queries you're running that somehow reproduce what you're describing. however, full text searches sometimes produce unexpected results, if one has the wrong assumptions about how they work. building an sqlfiddle *might* help. (also us in understanding)

Comment: Thank you @Jakumi I will edit the question as soon as I get to my computer